# java generic class cast

Tags: java, class, generics

Hello i have got hash map with value:

```
    private static final LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends Annotation> , Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>> annotationGeneratorMap = new LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>>();
```

and my numeric Generator looks like :

```
public abstract class NumericGenerator<T extends Number> extends AGenerator<T>{


public NumericGenerator(Field field) {
    super(field);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public T random() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

  }
```

And i have got problem when i need to put this class into hashmap :

```
annotationGeneratorMap.put(GenerateNumeric.class, NumericGenerator.class);
```

**And in eclipse i have got error the method is not applicable for the argument ???**

but :

```
        annotationGeneratorMap.put(GenerateNumeric.class, (Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>) NumericGenerator.class);
```

and @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is good ..:/

Can i do this without casting ?? `(Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>) NumericGenerator.class`

Answer (score 2):

use `Class<? extends AGenerator>` instead

```
LinkedHashMap<
    Class<? extends Annotation>, 
    Class<? extends AGenerator> > annotationGeneratorMap = new LinkedHashMap<>()
```

In Java, class can represent a raw type, but cannot represent a generic type.

There is a class for `List`, but there is no class for `List<String>`.

So you can declare `Class<? extends List>`, which is compatible with `ArrayList.class` etc. because raw type `ArrayList` is a subtype of `List`.

But `Class<? extends List<?>>` doesn't make much sense, because there is no class that is a subtype of `List<?>`.

And all thanks to erasure.

Answer (score 1):

Compile time check won't allow you to do that unless you cast it of course.

Information about generic types is lost at runtime, not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Following compiles without error on version `1.7.0_02`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

interface AGenerator<T> {}

interface A extends Annotation {}
class X implements AGenerator<X> {}

class E7 {
    private static final LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, 
        Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>> annotationGeneratorMap 
        = new LinkedHashMap<Class<? extends Annotation>, 
                            Class<? extends AGenerator<?>>>();


    void foo() {
        annotationGeneratorMap.put(A.class, X.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, `X` is a subtype of `AGenerator<?>`. but `X` is not generic, unlike OP's example.

Comment: @Miserable Variable but consider scenario like that that your X class user generics: class X<T extends Numver> implements AGenerator<T>

this is not allowed :/